# Simultaneous assignment in python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am a newbie at python programming.I am referring to a book "Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science." Which is oriented to python 2.Since I cannot lay my hands upon a basic book oriented to python 3, I am facing a syntax problem depicted below

```
>>> def f():
x,y=input("enter two numbers seperated by a comma: ")
s=x+y
d=x-y
print (s,d)
f()
```

The result i got was

```
>>> f()
enter two numbers seperated by a comma: 2,3
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
f()


File "<pyshell#9>", line 2, in f
x,y=input("enter two numbers seperated by a comma: ")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I tried to find the solution in some books like dive into python 3 and core python programming, but i think that they are way too high level for me right now.Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use the edit [link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33887662/edit) on your question to show your code. Don't post an image. You should copy/paste the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"input" returns only one value at the time, so you can't really assign it for two variables. If you expect two values you may want to split string by space or any other convenient separator.

```
>>> x,y = map(int, input("Enter x and y separated by comma: ").split(',', 1))
Enter x and y separated by comma: 1, 2
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```

split(var, 1) - make sure you split string only once into two pieces.
map(int...) - convert each string piece value into integer.

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function returns one `str` (in Python 3), which won't be automatically split into two variables. You need to do something like:

```
x, y = input('enter two numbers separated by a comma:').split(',')
```